# How to respond to 'attach' from Gmail? Responding to intent with attachment

Tags: android, email, android-intent, gmail, attachment

I am writing an android application. This app is built on top of Gmail. I want to add the ability to attach files from other apps. The first app I am working on doing this with is a custom Box app (made with the box sdk). I can currently send an intent, open an activity in the Box app, pick an attachment, and return. However, in my Box-SDK app, once an item is selected, I have no idea how to turn it into data that I can properly send back to my Gmail app (or any original sender of the intent). I also do not know how to send that data back to the originator of the intent.

I know setResult() is involved, but I am not sure where to put it or how to properly use it to carry the data chosen in box into the email app.

What's currently happening is it just goes back into gmail without an attachment and says that the download has finished.

Here is the code I currently have:

```
    private void onFileSelected(final int resultCode, final Intent data) {
        if (Activity.RESULT_OK != resultCode) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "fail", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else {
            final BoxAndroidFile file =     data.getParcelableExtra(FilePickerActivity.EXTRA_BOX_ANDROID_FILE);
            AsyncTask<Null, Integer, Null> task = new AsyncTask<Null, Integer, Null>() {

                @Override
                protected void onPostExecute(Null result) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "done downloading", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
//                    Intent result2 = new Intent();
//                    result2.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file://" + ));
//                    setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, result2);
////                    setResult(resultCode, data);
                    super.onPostExecute(result);
                    finish();
                }

                @Override
                protected void onPreExecute() {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "start downloading", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    super.onPreExecute();
                }

                @Override
                protected Null doInBackground(Null... params) {
                    BoxAndroidClient client = ((HelloWorldApplication) getApplication()).getClient();
                    try {
                        File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), file.getName());
                        Intent result2 = new Intent();
                        result2.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file://" + f.getAbsolutePath()));
                        setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, data);
//                        setResult(resultCode, data);
                        System.out.println(f.getAbsolutePath());
                        client.getFilesManager().downloadFile(file.getId(), f, null, null);
                    }
                    catch (Exception e) {
                    }
                    return null;
                }
            };
            task.execute();

        }
    }




@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == AUTH_REQUEST) {
        onAuthenticated(resultCode, data);
    }
    else if (requestCode == UPLOAD_REQUEST) {
        onFolderSelected(resultCode, data);
    }
    else if (requestCode == DOWNLOAD_REQUEST) {
        onFileSelected(resultCode, data);
    }
}
```

Comment: I managed to figure it out, by setting the result to a new intent with the file uri as the extra

Intent result2 = new Intent();
            result2.setData(Uri.parse("file://" + f.getAbsolutePath()));
            getActivity().setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, result2);

Answer (score 0):

Try using a file provider:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.html#ServeUri

From the page:

"There are a variety of ways to serve the content URI for a file to a client app. One common way is for the client app to start your app by calling startActivityResult(), which sends an Intent to your app to start an Activity in your app. In response, your app can immediately return a content URI to the client app or present a user interface that allows the user to pick a file. In the latter case, once the user picks the file your app can return its content URI. In both cases, your app returns the content URI in an Intent sent via setResult()"

From another stackoverflow answer:

```
public void showCameraScreen(View view) {
// BUILT IN CAMERA 
Intent camera = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);   
camera.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(getTempFile(this)) );   
this.startActivityForResult(camera, 1);

}   

private File getTempFile(Context context) {
// it will return /sdcard/MyImage.tmp
final File path = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), context.getPackageName());
if (!path.exists()) {
    path.mkdir();
}
return new File(path, "MyImage.tmp");
}

@Override
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
if (requestCode == 1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
    final File file = getTempFile(this);

    byte[] _data = new byte[(int) file.length()];
    try {
        InputStream in = new FileInputStream(file);
        in.read(_data);
        in.close();
        in = null;
        //DO WHAT YOU WANT WITH _data. The byte array of your image.
    } catch (Exception E) {

    }
}
}
```

We can modify this code, where it says //Do What you want with the _data, just call

```
public final void setResult (int resultCode, Intent data)
```